# What is the purpose of the "tag=stackoverfl08-20" tag in an Amazon url?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I just followed a [link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B8BAC6C) from an answer on a travel.se. I noticed that the resulting URL contains a stackoverfl tag ([http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00B8BAC6C/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B8BAC6C)). What is the purpose of Amazon tagging links coming from the various stack exchange platforms? I guess the tag wasn't added by the person answering that question, so it must be added automatically. 
 Is it part of the business model to acquire funds, or does it serve other purposes as well?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links and [similar questions on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon)

Answer (score 2):

You can check some old MSO questions discussing exactly this, particularly

- [Would it be a problem if all Amazon links were converted to affiliate links?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10948/would-it-be-a-problem-if-all-amazon-links-were-converted-to-affiliate-links)
- [Auto-Inserting Stack Overflow affiliate into all Amazon book links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/auto-inserting-stack-overflow-affiliate-into-all-amazon-book-links)

You can read from the responses that this change was somewhat controversial (and personally, I think with good reason), but the fact stands -- links to products on Amazon (not sure if it applies to all Amazon sites, but certainly for the main .com domain) are rewritten with an affiliation tag belonging to SE Inc., which is a way for them to earn some revenue. Some might call it a bit underhanded, and I'm ambivalent to the idea, but I can certainly recognize their need to earn some money to pay for the upkeep of Travel-SE and other SE sites.